# My sql Select IF returns the else result even if the condition is true

Tags: mysql

This request returns Else result 
"ELSE RESULT" even if the condition is true.

```
SELECT
   IF(Print_Server_Type='BW',SUM(Total_Impressions_Printed),'ELSE RESULT') AS BWTotalImpressions
FROM printedjob
WHERE
  Account=''
  And Job_Submission_Date>="2015-08-24"
  AND Job_Submission_Date<="2015-08-28";
```

Same request with the where condition that works fine

```
SELECT
  SUM(Total_Impressions_Printed) AS BWTotalImpressions
FROM printedjob
WHERE
  Account=''
  And Print_Server_Type='BW'
  And Job_Submission_Date>="2015-08-24"
  AND Job_Submission_Date<="2015-08-28";
```

I'm using the first request because I need the result to be a column from a select.

Comment: Can you edit above to post a sample of the table containing these rows, together with a sample of what you expect the query output to be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are mixing aggregate terms (like `SUM(Total_Impressions_Printed)`) and single-row terms (like `Print_Server_Type`). Seems like you're trying to return a row per value of `Print_Server_Type`, which means you're missing a `group by` clause:

```
SELECT   Print_Server_Type, 
         IF(Print_Server_Type = 'BW',
            SUM(Total_Impressions_Printed), 
            'ELSE RESULT') AS BWTotalImpressions
FROM     printedjob
WHERE    Account = '' AND 
         Job_Submission_Date >= "2015-08-24" AND 
         Job_Submission_Date <= "2015-08-28"
GROUP BY Print_Server_Type
```

Comment: The issue is that data contains both BW and color Print_Server_Type

Answer (score 0):

I think that your ELSE statement is written incorrectly. The else shouldn't be into quotes 'ELSE RESULT'... I would start by verifying to correct format to write the query.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed the issue , here is the request:

```
Select Account,SUM(Total_Impressions),SUM(BWTotalImpressions)
FROM (
    SELECT Account,Print_Server_Type,SUM(Total_Impressions_Printed) As Total_Impressions, 
    IF(Print_Server_Type='Color',SUM(Total_Color_Pages_Printed),'') AS ColorTotalImpressions,
    IF(Print_Server_Type='BW',SUM(Total_Impressions_Printed),
    IF(Print_Server_Type='Color',SUM(Total_Black_Only_Pages_Printed),'')) AS BWTotalImpressions
    FROM printedjob
    WHERE Job_Submission_Date>="2015-08-24" AND Job_Submission_Date<="2015-08-28"
    GROUP BY Account,Print_Server_Type
    )AS T
GROUP by Account;
```